Does serverless framework version 2 supports Node.js version 18 or higher
We got a lambda notification from AWS that follows -- AWS going to End of Support Life(EOL) for Node.js versions 16 or below after June-24. We are currently serverless frameworkVersion: '2' in our serverless.yml file. Does node.js 18 or higher version supports version 2 or do we need to upgrade to V3 for the same ?

Node.js 18 or higher version supports Serverless Framework version 2. Serverless Framework version 2 supports Node.js 12 and above, including Node.js 18 and higher versions. So, you can upgrade your Node.js runtime to a version 18 or higher, and your Serverless Framework version 2 configuration should still work.

Does Node.js actually document their support for Serverless Framework? That seems like an unusual thing for them to do.
